# In iOS, how do I programmatically display dynamically changing values in a text field?

Tags: ios, text, textbox, textfield, programmatically-created

I have Objective C code that continually updates a set of numerical values. I need to display these values on the screen. That's it! I can convert numerical values into a text string, no problem. But how do I display this string in a UI element? Do I use a text box or a text field or a text view, or a...? I cannot find examples to show how to pass a string from code into the UI. I assume I need to set up a text thingy, and then periodically refresh the contents of that text thingy when the values change?

I assume the answer is simple but is just obscured by a smokescreen of technical jargon.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any kind of interface created through code or the interfacebuilder / storyboard? If the later one is the case: connect the UITextField, or UITextView or UILabel as IBOutlet to your code.

Comment: Hi luk2302 - that sounds like the kind of answer I'm looking for :) I do have a .xib file and can drop-in UI elements. I have used IBOutlet before, and I can refer to that pattern. I'll give that a try. Thanks! -j

Comment: You are welcome, there are plenty of tutorials out there for that purpose, since it is one of the most basic interface builder operations, have a look at raywenderlich.com or just plain old youtube ;)

Answer (score 2):

From the UI perspective you might want something like a

- `UITextView` - multi-line text input
- `UITextField` - single-line text input
- `UILabel` - just text

For your purpose of just printing text, you should use `UILabel`, since you dont want / need any kind of input. You can access its text using:

```
// yourLabel is your current UILabel* you want to output yourValue to
yourLabel.text = yourValue;
```

Of course that `yourValue` needs to be converted to NSString before.

To actually get hold of the `UILabel`, you need to connect it from the Interface Builder as an `IBOutlet`. For tutorials on that topic, take a look at tutorials like [Interface Tutorials by Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) or youtube or just google `Interface Builder tutorial`.